# HTML works on every web-browser except IE 7

Tags: html, jsp, internet-explorer-7

Im having issue with my html code. It works on every web browser except IE 7. Can somebody help me understand why. I am knew to html but experienced in Java. The code below is a excerpt from my JSP. Any help is greatly appreciated. I posted this once and everyone tore me apart. Please bear with me. Thankyou to any one who can help. 
-The issue is that the html appears in other browsers but IE returns an empty page.

```
<html>
  <%@include file = "../common/emxUIConstantsInclude.inc"%>
  <form name=LocationSelectionForm method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
      <tr> 
        <th nowrap> <%=header%></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>&nbsp;</tr>
<%
      int i = 0;
      Iterator locationItr = locations.iterator();
      while (locationItr.hasNext()){
        String loc = (String) locationItr.next();

%>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"> 
<%
            if (currentLocation!=null && loc.equals(currentLocation)){

%> 
              <input type="radio" name="location" value="<%=loc%>" checked> <%=loc%>

<%
            } else {
%>
              <input type="radio" name="location" value="<%=loc%>"> <%=loc%>
<%
            }
%>
          </td>
        </tr>
<%
        i++;
      }
%>
    </table>
  </form> 

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javaScript">//<![CDATA[
  <!-- hide JavaScript from non-JavaScript browsers
    function setLocation(){
      form = document.LocationSelectionForm;
      form.action = "MERPLocationContextProcess.jsp";
      form.submit();
    }
  //Stop hiding here -->//]]>
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the `<html>` starting block?

Comment: right above " <%@include file = "../common/emxUIConstantsInclude.inc"%>"

Comment: Also would have been nice for you to (a) specify exactly how the HTML is "now working" and (b) reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.  And maybe (c) provide the actual, rendered HTML rather than the JSP source, since the JSP part of the picture is presumably irrelevant.

Comment: HTML Working means my two radio buttons appear. One of them checked. Not working means nothing appears. whats really weird that when even though nothing is there i can select all and copy to a text file and the text of my radio buttons appear

Comment: Suggestion: run your code through HTML validator (http://validator.w3.com) and fix _every_ error and warning before asking for help. *Your question is the equivalent of someone writing a term paper and wondering why they received a low grade for spelling mistakes when they couldn't be bothered to run spell check on it before submitting it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: I needed to add `<body>` & `</body>` statements:

```
<html>
   <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Submitting Radio Buttons</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
     <BODY>
  <%@include file = "../common/emxUIConstantsInclude.inc"%>
  <form name=LocationSelectionForm method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
      <tr> 
        <th nowrap> <%=header%></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>&nbsp;</tr>
<%
      int i = 0;
      Iterator locationItr = locations.iterator();
      while (locationItr.hasNext()){
        String loc = (String) locationItr.next();
%>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"> 
<%
            if (currentLocation!=null && loc.equals(currentLocation)){
%>
              <input type="radio" name="location" value="<%=loc%>" checked> <%=loc%>
<%
            } else {
%>
              <input type="radio" name="location" value="<%=loc%>"> <%=loc%>
<%
            }
%>
          </td>
        </tr>
<%
        i++;
      }
%>
    </table>
  </form> 
   </BODY>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javaScript">//<![CDATA[
  <!-- hide JavaScript from non-JavaScript browsers
    function setLocation(){
      form = document.LocationSelectionForm;
      form.action = "MERPLocationContextProcess.jsp";
      form.submit();
    }
  //Stop hiding here -->//]]>
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: The `</body>` should be the very last thing before the `</html>`. It probably works right now, but it might cause you further problems down the line if you don't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Check you browser cache (reset it) .. IE all versions have tendency to over-cache.

Answer (score 1):

First HTML bug I see:

```
<tr>&nbsp;</tr>
```

This is invalid HTML. `<tr>` elements must contain only `<td>` or `<th>` elements.

I don't know if that's enough to kill rendering on IE7, but it definitely needs fixing.

Second error I see is that you haven't got a `<body>` tag (you also only have a closing `<html>` tag, but you state in the comments that this is opened above the pasted code). `<body>` is required. Again, not sure if it would break the rendering, but it certainly has potential to do so.

Comment: `&nbsp;` isn't an element, it's an entity

Comment: ok <body> would be under ,/header. im assuming. then i would close the body </body> after i populate my radio buttons. so maybe take out <tr> and sub in <body>. again im a noob at html

Comment: yeah but he is right, should be 
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

Comment: Spudley your answer was the most useful. If i could vote it up i would. Thanks again

Comment: @Dean - no problem :-) You only need 15 points before you can vote, so you shouldn't have too long to wait. In the meanwhile, if it solved the problem, feel free to accept it using the tick icon (you can accept an answer to your question no matter what your score). Alternatively, I note that you answered the question yourself with the correct answer; you should 'accept' that answer if it's the one you went with. (accepting your own answers is perfectly valid)

Comment: gotcha. SO is really detailed. ill catch on as i go along. thanks for getting me going